# Using path parameters on static website through Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

I have a static website on S3 and Cloudfront.  I'd like to pass through a value to the static site javascript using a path parameter instead of query parameter.

e.g.

```
mysupersite.com/123
```

instead of

```
mysupersite.com?id=123
```

How I can configure Cloudfront to use the same static files for any id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a [Lambda@Edge function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) for the `Origin Request` event.

By using a Lambda@Edge function you can parse the request and take the id from the path and add it as a query string attribute to the request that will be forwarded to your origin.

By doing this the browser request looks like

```
example.com/123
```

But the request forwarded to S3 looks like

```
example.com?id=123
```

If you take a look at [these examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) it should help you to get the idea of how you would use it.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  So this would mean than the browser would see example.com/123 but the static pages would be retrieved from s3://example.com/ (root folder), which is exactly what I want.  I'll try it out now...

Comment: OK great, let me know if you need anymore help :)

Comment: Works great.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)